# Fatal error: Call to undefined function cypher_previousposts() in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have wordpress site. I have installed modern-blue-green-120070612-2 theme.Then i got an error message on the right hand side "Fatal error: Call to undefined function cypher_previousposts() in mydomain\wp-content\themes\modern-blue-green-120070612-2\sidebar.php on line 59.

Does any one know this? Please help me ....

Thaks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cypher_previousposts` seems to be coming from a plug-in named "Previous Posts" (see e.g. [here](http://mialao.net/wp-content/plugins/cypher_previous-posts/readme.txt)). The author seems to be running the site [cypherhackz.net](http://www.cypherhackz.net/). I'd recommend you search for this plugin in the official WP plugin repository and install it from there.